# Query to Replace a value with a different value in a table

Tags: oracle11g

I would like to replace a value `Test` to `Mess` in Column `A` in a table `T` where the value is `Var` in Column `B` in the same table.

Please someone help me with the query as I'm new to Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy, try this:

```
UPDATE t
SET A =  REPLACE(A, 'Test', 'Mess')
WHERE B = 'Var';
```

or if You want not replace, but full text update in A column, you can make like this :

```
UPDATE t
SET A =  'Mess'
WHERE B = 'Var' and A = 'Test';
```